# google maps api markers zoom works in only 1 listener

Tags: android, google-maps, markers

Im trying to get the zoom out of any markers i make, for this i did a method where i create all the markers with their owns `setOnMarkerClickListener`  , the thing is when i run the app it only does the zoom to miami but not to the others, i dont know what im missing

```
private float zoomLevel = 15;

public void Veterinarias (GoogleMap googleMap){
        rMap = googleMap;


       final LatLng bvillia = new LatLng(-31.4223465,-64.1829377);
       final LatLng shangai = new LatLng(31.2071315,121.2287258);
        final LatLng miami = new LatLng(25.7959734,-80.3209081);

        rMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bvillia).title("Bv arturo illia"));
        rMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(shangai).title("Shangai"));
        rMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miami).title("Miami"));

        rMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String name= marker.getTitle();

                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Bv arturo illia")){

                    rMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bvillia, zoomLevel));


                }

                return false;
            }
        });


        rMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String name= marker.getTitle();

                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Shangai")){

                    rMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(shangai, zoomLevel));


                }


                return false;
            }
        });

        rMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String name= marker.getTitle();

                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Miami")){

                    rMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miami, zoomLevel));


                }



                return false;
            }
        });



    }




}
```

pd: is there a way to zoom in progressive and not in just one time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Marker Listener gets set on the Map so you're just overriding the previous listeners with the last one you set. If you move your conditions all to one listener, it should work fine.

```
rMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String name= marker.getTitle();

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Bv arturo illia")){
                rMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bvillia, zoomLevel));

            }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Shangai")){
                rMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(shangai, zoomLevel));

            }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Miami")){
                rMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miami, zoomLevel));
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are right, what a bad move from me HAHAHA didnt even notice it